# Error in converting desrializing JSON array

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json

I have the following function:

```
   function pqGrid_getData(grid)
{
    debugger;
    var ret = { parentData: null, childData: [] };

    data = grid.option('dataModel.data'); //data of master grid.
    ret.parentData = data;

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var rd = data[i],
            dt = rd.pq_detail,
            child;
        if (dt && dt.child) {
            //dt.child is reference to the DOM node of the child grid.
            child = $(dt.child).data('pqGrid');//reference to instance of child grid.
            if (child != null) {
                var dataChild = child.option('dataModel.data');//data of child grid.
                ret.childData.push(dataChild);
            }
        }
    }
    debugger;

    return ret;
}
```

I am getting the data of PQGrid into an object to send it to the server.

I then stringify() ret.childData, so I have:

```
[[{"ID":"PLC0000001","Name":"CASH","ClientID":"CLN00742","Status":"1","name":"","Class":"","ClassID":"","InsuranceCardNo":"","AsAtDate":"24-07-2017","LoggedInUserName":"","ValidUntil":"24-07-2018","PayerID":"","PatientID":"","CreationDate":"","LoggedInUserID":"","Image":"","pq_cellselect":{"Name":true}}]]
```

but when I try to desirialize (Using NewtonSoft) it in the server using:

```
 List<MyObj> lstPol = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyObj>>(jsn);
```

I get the following error:

> **Additional information: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'MyObj' because the type requires a JSON
>   object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.**

ret.ParenData is working fine.
I guess the error is that the chilData is an array and not a normal object, but unable to figure out the solution. Thanks

Comment: Try `DeserializeObject<List<List<MyObj>>>` instead of `DeserializeObject<List<MyObj>>` because JSON properties wrapped inside 2 arrays before starting curly brace.

Comment: Because `dataChild` is a list. You are trying to convert `List<List<MyObj>>` into `List<MyObj>`.